# Vb.net Copy file to all subfolder

Tags: vb.net

I have a Folder called Users. This Folder a 3 subfolders at the root: A , B, and C. How would I use vb.net to copy a file into the root of all of these subfolders?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Could you show us some code that indicates you've started working on it and are stuck?

Comment: We would love to help, but this comes across as a "write my code for me" question. This website is for learning and not a free coding service. Please show us what you have done and we might be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into this example

```
Dim fi As New FileInfo("D:\file1.txt")
Dim dirs As DirectoryInfo() = New DirectoryInfo("D:\Root").GetDirectories()

For Each d As DirectoryInfo In dirs
    fi.CopyTo(d.FullName, True)
Next
```

Hope it helps.